# How to send live video from one computer to other using opencv...i want to send frames serially using RS232

Tags: c++, opencv, serial-port

i want to create a server client codes on visual studio. server is used to capture live frames from webcam of laptop and send the frames serially to other laptop
where client side code is used to receive the live video taken in server side serially 
i want to transmit video serially. 
i am using visual studio C++, OpenCV4.1.
The codes that i have done before to transmit and receive live video using tcp/ip (winsock)and opencv in visual studio C++.

Comment: Are you sure you can gain enough speed via that connection? Other than that, your question is too broad to answer.

Comment: speed is not my concern. it's my task to do this serially

Comment: i have also done the project of sending live vedio from one laptop to other using opencv and winsock libraries via TCP/IP connection

Comment: Still too broad though. Show what you tried and where you're stuck with it specifically.

Comment: For example, how about connecting a server laptop and a client laptop with PPTP using a serial port? If there is a program that already works with WinSock and TCP/IP connection, will it work as it is?

Comment: I am using visual Studio C++ , OpenCV libraries . I have already made one project which is to transmit and receive live video BTW two laptops. i have done this transmission using Tcp/ip portal (winsock) and video part is done by opencv . Now i want to do this same project but now i have to transmit and receive live video serially . i have to communicate both laptops serially to transmit and receive live video captured using opencv terms(vediocapture(0)).I have no idea how to communicate two laptops serially and how send and receive any data on visual studio C++ using serial communication.

Comment: so basically my task is to transmit and receive live video serially in visual studio C++ and using opencv

Comment: For example, with these resources as a reference, can you connect two laptops with a serial port via TCP/IP without the need for programming? [PPP on Windows 10](https://ig8g.com/out/utilities/PPP/PPPWindows10SetupNotes_RevA.pdf), [Establishing a PPP connection under Windows 7](https://ig8g.com/out/utilities/PPP/Establishing%20a%20PPP%20connection%20under%20Windows%207.pdf), [Installing and configuring a PPP null-modem connection on Windows 7](https://mikebeach.org/2012/08/30/installing-and-configuring-a-ppp-null-modem-connection-on-windows-7/)

Comment: if i consider this connection ppp on windows 10, but my question is still  be the same  that how can i achieve my ultmate goal of transmitting and receiving live video. i have made two code one is for server and the  other is client  on visual studio c++ . link of codes:https://github.com/xanthium-enterprises/Serial-Programming-Win32API-C/blob/master/USB2SERIAL_Write/Transmitter%20(PC%20Side)/USB2SERIAL_Write_W32.c ,https://github.com/xanthium-enterprises/Serial-Programming-Win32API-C/blob/master/USB2SERIAL_Read/Reciever%20(PC%20Side)/USB2SERIAL_Read_W32.c

Comment: but  i have made changes in these code according to my requirement , In this code they are sending Alphabet "A" serially . but i have used opencv and send the Mat image data through it. i have made changes but still getting errors .. (cant open port) and all the other errors..

Comment: If you can connect two laptops with the serial port PPP, you should be able to communicate with WinSock with the IP address and port number specified, just as you would with an Ethernet connection.

Comment: If you really want to communicate using a serial port, there is such a library. [CSerialPort/CSerialPort2](http://www.naughter.com/serialport.html), [Serial library for C++](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/992/Serial-library-for-C), [Windows Serial Communication Component Library](https://www.marshallsoft.com/serial-communication-library.htm)